# detect attribute of variable - jquery

Tags: jquery

I am working on a script and not sure why this isn't working

```
function moveIn($selector) {
if( $( $selector[left] ) != null ){
    $direction = 'left';
}else{
    $direction = 'right';
}
```

This is does work:

```
if( $( '#hello[left]' ) != null ){
```

This is essentially what I am trying to get spit out. It seems the brackets are causing the problem. How else would this be written? Tips for future coding?
Thanks

Entire function:

```
function moveIn($selector) {
if( $( $selector + '[left]' ) != null ){
    $direction = 'left';
}else{
    $direction = 'right';
}
var animation = {};
    animation[$direction] = 0;
$($selector).animate(animation, 1500);
}
```

Comment: Tip, you shouldn't put `$` in front of nearly *all* your variables; it may have some usefulness if it's a jQuery object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're passing `"#hello"` as the selector, you are then trying to get the `left` property of a string, which doesn't exist.

`"#hello[left]"`, on the other hand, searches for an element with the ID `hello` and a `left` *attribute*.

They are not the same. Try `$selector+"[left]"`

Comment: Yes that worked but my function still isn't working right. From what you see there should that work? if the selector has the left attribute fill the direction variable with the string left else make it right...?

Comment: Yes, but what are you doing with the `$direction` variabe?

Comment: Okay, what are the initial values of the left and right positions?

Comment: left is -260px right is -250px. they are two boxes that slide in from the left and right

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21491/discussion-between-user980988-and-kolink)